# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module. import typescript file into JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working on angular 10. I need to use typescript angular service in jQuery file.
When I am importing TypeScript service file in jquery it gives me the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I am using below import statment in jQuery file:

```
import { priceFilteredByService } from "../../app/service/category-filtered-by/electronics/laptops/price-filtered-by-service";
```

priceFilteredByService is Angular typescript file. I need to access its function from a javascript file.

You find below javascript file:

```
import { laptopsFilteredByService } from "../../app/service/category-filtered-by/electronics/laptops/laptops-filtered-by-service";
import { priceFilteredByService } from "../../app/service/category-filtered-by/electronics/laptops/price-filtered-by-service";

!(function ($) {
    laptopFilteredByService: laptopsFilteredByService;
    priceFilteredByService: priceFilteredByService;
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
      "use strict";
    
    $('#price-range-submit').hide();

    $("#min_price,#max_price").on('change', function () {

      var min_price_range = parseInt($("#min_price").val());

      var max_price_range = parseInt($("#max_price").val());

      this.priceFilteredByService.getPriceMinMaxFilter()
      this.priceFilteredByService.setMinAED(min_price_range);
      this.priceFilteredByService.setMaxAED(max_price_range);
      this.laptopFilteredByService.getSelectedFilters()  
      
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your javascript compiler does not consider this file a module.
If you don't have already, you need to add compiler / bundler step to you workflow-

Comment: can you tell me how to access typescript .ts funcitons in javacript .js using angular.

Comment: You need to compile typescript to javascript with something. Typically projects use typescript compiler or webpack & webpack typerscript plugin or something to create handle modules. If you don't have compile step, you need one.

Comment: any idea if angular provide installable extension or plugin, or npm command. any practical code example. thanks

Comment: Also the `<script>` tag needs `type=module`. That's the *real* problem, though of course importing TypeScript directly into the browser won't work.